# Exercise of counting bits

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways to write a sequence of bits exists with the following conditions:

i.) The sequence has to start with a 1

ii.) the sequence has to include another 3 ones

iii.) The sequence has a total of 12 zeros

iv.) The sequence always has at least two zeros behind each one without the first one

The answer is 35, but I obtain this result and I don't know what is wrong:

Fix the  first 1 and represent the other ones like bars and the zeros like stars (I only use 6 stars because I already fixed two of the stars behind each bar):

1 | | | $\star$ $\star$ $\star$ $\star$ $\star$ $\star$

The I applied:

$\left(\begin{matrix}
3+6 \\
3
\end{matrix}\right) = 84$

Can you help me find the error? Thanks!!

Comment: I agree with your answer. $35$ is $\binom73$, so I suspect that either whoever produced the answer simply miscalculated, or there were supposed to be only $10$ zeroes.